# Django: Any way to change "upload_to" property of FileField without resorting to magic?

Tags: python, django

[See this blog post](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2007/07/31/uploading-images-to-a-dynamic-path-with-django/)... It's quite old so maybe things have changed. But in my experimenting they have not. In order to change the model field FileField `upload_to` path dynamically, you must resort to using `signals` and creating custom `model fields`. Nasty. I can't imagine that having a dynamic upload path is such a special use case that it's not addressed by the standard Django framework? Am I missing something? Is there any other way to accomplish this?

In essence I want to do this:

```
def MyModel(models.Model):
    fileUpload = models.FileField(upload_to='media/', null=True, blank=True)

def save(self, **kwargs):
    # Retrieve the user's id/pk from their profile
    up = UserProfile.objects.get(email=self.email)

    # All their uploads go into their own directory
    self.file_image.upload_to = up.id

    super(MyModel, self).save()
```

However, in the 10 different implementations I tried, Django hates all of them. For this one in particular, the file is uploaded to the default path `'media/'`.

I've tried scraping a modelform for parameters and passing those parameters into a dict object, create a MyModel object, set the MyModel.fileUpload.upload_to parameter, then copy the dict into the model and save. Doesn't work.

I also tried to override the `__init__` method, but guess what? That is so early in the object creation that it doesn't actually have `self.email` defined yet! So that doesn't work.

Any ideas or must I follow the arcane solution outlined in the original link?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So there is actually a fairly easy solution to this, in the `FileField` field, the `upload_to` keyword argument can actually take a function as a parameter. The function that you specify in your `upload_to` kwarg should have this signature.

```
def my_awesome_upload_function(instance, filename):
    """ this function has to return the location to upload the file """
 
     return os.path.join('/media/%s/' % instance.id, filename)
```

In this case, `instance` is the instance of your model that has the `FileField`, and `filename` is the filename of the uploaded file. So your model like in your example above would look like this:

```
def MyModel(models.Model):
    fileUpload = models.FileField(upload_to=my_awesome_upload_function, null=True, blank=True)
```

If this makes sense you can now change `my_awesome_upload_function` to generate you path to upload the file to based on your preference, given the model instance and filename of the file that has been uploaded.

Comment: You shouldn't include the `/media/` part. The returned path is relational to the path defined in the `MEDIA_ROOT` setting.

Comment: For any future users - @beruic makes a good point.  I included the media folder in my path and the result was that Django generated random file names.  It took me two hours to find the solution!

Comment: @artifex_knowledge are you sure it is not just because you uploaded a file with the same name to the same folder multiple times? That will make Django add a random suffix to the file name (before the extension).

Comment: @beruic - Very sure, my files each has a unique, dynamically assigned folder (date and time stamped). The actual file names were registered only when I removed the media folder from the path.

Comment: @artifex_knowledge - That is weird. I'd expect it to just add a directory layer more, such that it would just be `[your_media_folder]/media/[the_rest_of_the_path]`. Might the difference lie in whether you start the path with a `/` or not?

Comment: @beruic I use a small function to generate a unique path for the upload_to attribute of my model's FileField.  The base folder name (date stamp + user name) has no path separators in as I use `os.path.join` to build the final path.  No idea why this oddity, but I seem to get these often!

Comment: @artifex_knowledge Do you have a bug at the Django issue tracker?

Comment: @beruic Not yet no, under pressure to finish three projects - I'll have to see if I can duplicate the issue before submitting, in case I missed something.

Comment: This is not working when you're creating an object for the first time. In fact the id will be None.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this combination in your `models.py` file for `upload_to`:

```
def content_file_name(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['content', filename])

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name, null=False, verbose_name="File")
```

You can change the word 'content' to any string that you want to use to name the directory that it's going to save the file to.  So in this case the path would be: `/media/content/<file_name>`

Comment: It was a 3 way tie between me, you, and mgrouchy. Unfortunately, I could only accept 1 answer, but I still wanted to thank you. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Same blog, that I referenced before, also mentioned the [newer solution](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/25/dynamic-upload-paths-in-django/).

```
import os
from django.db import models

def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('photos', str(instance.id), filename)

class Photo(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path)
```

Here he uses the id of the actual object. Of course you can use whatever you want. But this answers my question.