# How to Create a storage folder using User name and id in django restfull api

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a video file that is uploaded by a user, I want to create a separate folder in the media/Smat/name/id directory  by using the name and id of the uploaded file.

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
import cv2
import tempfile
# from .utils import get_uploaded_video
from django.utils import timezone
import os

def upload_to(instance, filename):
    now = timezone.now()
    base, extension = os.path.splitext(filename.lower())
    return f"Smat/{now:%Y-%m-%d}"

class MyVideo(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    videofile= models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to, null=True, verbose_name="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ": " + str(self.videofile)
```

**seriliazer.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import MyVideo
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 

class MyVideoSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyVideo
        fields = fields = ['id', 'url', 'name', 'date', 'videofile']
        

class UploadVideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyVideo
        fields = ['videofile']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video file gets saved before MyVideo instance. So I was able to get around this by splitting the saving to two phases:

The first part simply checks if there is an absence of a pk, if there is it sets the videofile instance to None

The second part simply check for the pk before saving the field to the model

refer to this link for more insite [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968532/django-admin-file-upload-with-current-model-id)

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

_UNSAVED_FILEFIELD = 'unsaved_filefield'

@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyVideo)
def skip_saving_file(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not instance.pk and not hasattr(instance, _UNSAVED_FILEFIELD):
        setattr(instance, _UNSAVED_FILEFIELD, instance.videofile)
        instance.videofile = None

@receiver(post_save, sender=MyVideo)
def save_file(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and hasattr(instance, _UNSAVED_FILEFIELD):
        instance.videofile = getattr(instance, _UNSAVED_FILEFIELD)
        instance.save()        
        # delete it if you feel uncomfortable...
        # instance.__dict__.pop(_UNSAVED_FILEFIELD)
```

Answer (score 0):

That can be achieved by changing your `upload_to` function to something like

```py
import calendar
import time


def upload_to(instance, filename):
    ts = calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())
    filepath = f"Smat/{ts}"
    if instance:
        filepath = f"Smat/{instance.name}/{instance.id}"
    base, extension = os.path.splitext(filename.lower())
    return filepath
```

Comment: I get a None for the `instance.id`. I think the reason is because I don't have `id` as a field in the model

Comment: If you changed your pk field in your model, then use the pk field

Comment: If you still get an error, the print `instance` and show the output

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by changing the pk field in my model

Comment: Just print `instance` within your upload_to function and show the result

Comment: When I print instance, it doesn't print any value in the console.
according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207065/python-django-how-to-upload-a-file-with-a-filename-based-on-instance-pk) and [post](https://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/25/dynamic-upload-paths-in-django/) you need to make sure the model instance was saved before you upload the file. Could this be the reason why I get a None for `instance.id`

Comment: what do you think is a way around this

Comment: Yeah that is the reason, the model instance needs to be saved first

Comment: I have updated my answer you can try that. If the user instance has not been saved it will use timestamp as the folder name

Comment: It still displays none for the id. Is the a way I can use the id associated with the model to create a save path like `model_class.id`.